# Pulling email attachment w/ Python automatically

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, email

I can't get my scrip to pull attachments from emails that came into the "Inbox" today. It starts  with the emails that came in "Yesterday." How can I get it to start looking at emails from today?

```
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime as datetime

def subject_name(file_text):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    weekday = now.weekday()
    if weekday == 0:
        today = now - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    else: today = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    today = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    today = file_text + str(today)
    return today
file_text = 'Inventory Margin Report for '
today = subject_name(file_text)
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
i = 0
while i < 10:

    if message.Subject == 'Inventory Margin Report for 2019-08-01':
        print('x')
    else:
        print(message.Subject)
    i += 1
    message = messages.GetNext()
        try:
            attachments = message.Attachments
            attachment = attachments.Item(1)
            attachment.SaveASFile() #
            message = messages.GetNext()

        except:
            message = messages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming that the Inbox was already sorted by time received. However it is not. so the fix is adding this line: messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True) before calling .GetFirst()